# Comparison against Double.TYPE and Double.class

Tags: java, class, reflection, types, primitive

Actually this is not a question, since I will provide the answer right away, so you don't fall for the same thing:

I wanted to check (using reflection) if a `Field` is a primitive or one of the wrapper classes.

I checked using `cl.isPrimitive()` and comparisons like `c==Boolean.TYPE`, but according to my debugger, Boolean.TYPE.toString returns "boolean", instead of "Boolean".

Answer (score 1):

`Double.TYPE == double.class` will return `true`.
`Double.class != Double.TYPE` will also return `true`.

They (double.class and Double.TYPE) somehow represent the same thing, don't ask me why...

If you want to compare against [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), compare against `Double.class`.
If you want to compare against `double`, compare against `double.class` or `Double.TYPE`.

Though I haven't tested it with all primitives, it should be the same for all other primitives and their wrappers.

I hope this will save someone at least as many minutes as it took me to write this.

Comment: It says so in the javadoc, the `.TYPE` field of all of the wrapper classes _is_ the class of the primitive types. Plus this really isn't how StackOverflow is meant to be used...

Comment: Yes, I know, but its confusing at least... [You think so?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: `int.class` is compiled as `Integer.TYPE` at the bytecode level (why they don't simply use a primitive class constant pool entry is beyond me, but it's what it is), and this applies to all the other primitive types also (including `void`: `void.class` is compiled as `Void.TYPE`). So they really are equivalent.

Comment: Not in the slightest. `Double.class` is the class for `Double`s. `Double.TYPE` is the class for `double`s. I've used this before and I find it perfectly straightforward. And considering you answered your own "question," obviously you understood it as well.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Yes, after some searching and trying. It **is** straightforward, once you know that int.class==Integer.TYPE...